# WPF Particular TabItem Width Behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, width, tabcontrol, tabitem

I've this code with TabItems added Dynamycally in CodeBehind (C#):

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabList" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Transparent" SelectionChanged="tabList_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            <Image Source="myImage></Image>
                        </Button>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnPin" Checked="btnDisablex" Unchecked="btnDisablex" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                //Many Useless Things
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                     //Other Many Useless Things
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

And with the following Style in User Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
                            Background="White"
                            BorderBrush="#888" 
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                            CornerRadius="2,12,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        //Many Useless MultiTrigger and Datatrigger
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The code is working fine, until I add more tabs and the window width is no longer enough, but the TabControl behaviour is strange: the TabItem width becomes larger and the first TabItems disappear.

I just want the TabItem width reduces or just that the olders "disappear" but keeping always the same width. Why this is not working?

This is the screenshot taken in normal conditions

[Normal view working OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGDYP.jpg)

Here it's clear the problem: when I add more tabs (or I reduce the window/grid width) the tab width becomes larger

[Tab View Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB1UD.jpg)